# Both fields not filled in log in statement

Tags: php, if-statement, authentication

So im building a classic paged based log in system with Php. At the moment i am making sure the form fields work as they should and provide the correct echo messages. I have them working for if the Username field is empty, password field is empty and if both fields have been filled in.

My problem is i cant seem to get the fourth statement to work which is receiving a response when both fields have not been filled in.

I have tried adding:

```
}elseif(!$email)&&(!$PassWord){
echo "You did not fill in two form fields";
}
```

To the bottom of the below statements but i just keep getting errors. Any solutions as i am rather new to php?

```
if($Action=="Login"){
if(!$email){
echo "You did not fill in the User Name form field";
}elseif(!$PassWord){
echo "You did not fill in the Password form field";
}else{
echo "Welcome $email. You filled in both form fields correctly";
}
```

Comment: You'll want to put the dual condition first.  By nature, one of the other three is showing true first, so you can never make it to the fourth.

Answer (score 2):

Put this first in your conditional statement, before you check the rest.
    'if((!$email)&&(!$password))'
As written now, every time you run through your conditional statement, you're setting off the 'if(!$email)' condition, and never making it through to your 'if((!$email)&&(!$password))'.

so it would look approximately like this:

```
if((!$email)&&(!$password)){ echo 'all blank'; } /// requires both to be blank
elseif(!$email){ echo 'email blank'; } /// only requires email to be blank
elseif(!$password){ echo 'password blank'; } ///only requires password to be blank
else{echo 'good job!';} /// SUCCESS!
```

Comment: Agree but also do mention that current condition has syntax error in it.

Comment: My +1 is pending for an example :-)

Answer (score 1):

The first code block should contain:

```
elseif(!$email && !$PassWord)
```

The second one is missing a closing `}`.

As a tip, try indenting your code so it'll be more readable and easier to debug. And also try following some conventions: camelCased variable names (or underscore variable names) - don't capitalize some variable names, and some not; don't capitalize and camelCase the same variable name. Sticking with these conventions will make your life a lot easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have syntax error in this line `elseif(!$email)&&(!$PassWord){`

Try this,

```
elseif(!$email && !$PassWord){
    ..^                     ^...
```

instead of

```
elseif(!$email)&&(!$PassWord){
```

Your code should be like,

```
if($Action=="Login"){
    if( !$email && !$PassWord ){
         echo "You did not fill in two form fields";
    }else if(!$email){
        echo "You did not fill in the User Name form field";
    }elseif(!$PassWord){
        echo "You did not fill in the Password form field";
    }else{
        echo "Welcome $email. You filled in both form fields correctly";
    }
}
```